# sliding tab menu one to another

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a content tabs which is click to content for each tabs that is working fine, I would like to slide tabs when someone click to another tab then active tabs color slide to another tabs, I want sliding tabs one tabs to another after switching, below html and css for tabs, please help thanks in advance

```css
.tab{ font-family: "Gotham"; }
.tab .nav-tabs{
    background-color: #c8e8e9;
    padding: 0 0 1px;
    border: none;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a{
    color: #41b3b7;
    background: #c8e8e9;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
    border-radius:50px;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover,
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:hover{
    color: #000;
    border: none;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a:before,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a:after{
    background-color: #ffc20e;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:before,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover:before{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:after,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover:after{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #ffc20e;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.tab .tab-content{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a i{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.tabs .title{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color:#101010;
    font-weight:100;
}
.tabs .title-head{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color:#2aa5ab;
    font-weight:500;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs about-sii-tab" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Heading</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Heading 2</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Heading 3</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Heading 4</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Heading 5</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Heading 6</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what are you trying to achieve . Is it you want to change color of clicked tab by active class or something else . Be some more specific about details

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery Solution**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".about-sii-tab li").click(function() {
    $(".about-sii-tab li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

If you are using Jquery on your project you can easy achieve this by using above code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and prompt time, its not working for sliding tabs